# NetworkX weird routing result

Tags: python, networkx, shortest-path, osmnx

i have the following problem:

I've downloaded an OSM street graph via OSMNX, converted it to an undirected graph (i don't need two lanes of a street). Then i manually added additional nodes to the graph and the corresponding edges.

When i do some routing, like Traveling Salesman or Dijkstras, i've got weird results. The route shows pathes,from node to node, where no edge is existing and thus with not connection between the nodes.

An simple example:

The first picture shows the graph. The second one shows a shortes path routing from node 1 to node 2, with the expected result. The third picture shows a routing from node 2 to node 1 and the weird result: the straight line on the left, marked by the arrow.

[Routing example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSfLs.png)

I don't know, why this weird result occurs. I've checked every edge and node by hand and everything is allright. The graph is fine... And this problem occurs multiple times in my graph.
I also checked the routing path by hand and it is also fine. So is it just a display error or is there more behind it?

I appreciate any help :)

Greetings